# Proving $x^{3} + y^{3} = z^{3}$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$ with $x,y,x \neq 0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic

I am wondering how I can prove $x^{3} + y^{3} = z^{3}$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$ with $x,y,x\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$.

I got a tip from my friend to **" Calculate first $a^{3}$ modulo $7$ for all $0 < a < 7$ "** but I can't figure out how to use this information.

$1^3$ mod $7$ = 1

$2^3$ mod $7$ = 1

$3^3$ mod $7$ = 6

$4^3$ mod $7$ = 1

$5^3$ mod $7$ = 6

$6^3$ mod $7$ = 6

Comment: So $x^3\equiv1$ or $6\pmod 7$. Similarly for $y^3$. What about $x^3+y^3$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Using (a + b) % n == ((a%n) + (b%n)) % n and knowing that $x^{3} \equiv 1 or 6 \pmod{7}$ same for $y^{3}$. Can I look at the three possibilities that are:


$x^{3} + y^{3} \equiv 6 + 6 = 12 \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$


$x^{3} + y^{3} \equiv 6 + 1 = 7 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$


$x^{3} + y^{3} \equiv 1 + 1 = 12 \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$


and then draw what conclusion?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel has already given the answer .

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Was your answer not correct?

Comment: @Anonymous It seems to me like your edit substantially changes the question, since it completely changes the ring where the solutions are taken to live from $\mathbb Z_7$ to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @TokenToucan uh oh , my mistake . Thanks for editing it again .

Comment: @AnginaSeng can you please check my response comment to you above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've shown is that for $a\in \mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$, the value of $a^3$ is $\pm 1$ if $a\neq 0$ and is $0$ if $a=0$.

That means solutions in $\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$ of the equation
$$x^3 + y^3 = z^3$$
are equivalent to solutions to
$$a+b=c$$
with $a,b,c$ taken from $\{-1,0,1\}$ (still working in $\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$).

You restricted to the case where none of $x,y,z$ are zero, which further restricts $a,b,c$ to $\{-1,1\}$. But it is clear that there is no way to solve the above system in this fashion, because $a+b$ can only be one of $-2,0,2$ (corresponding to both $-1$, exactly one of each, and both $+1$) yet $a+b=c$ and $c$ must be one of $-1$ or $+1$.

Comment: Most of this makes sense to me, thank you! Could you please clarify the equivalence between the two equations?

Comment: I replace $x^3$ by $a$, $y^3$ by $b$, and $z^3$ by $c$, but keep their values restricted to the possible values of cubes, since that’s what they were originally. One can go the other way by taking each a,b,c value and just picking something which cubes to it (there could be multiple).